# how to display value of acf field from selected elementor control

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have created elementor SELECT control that shows all post from  'post_type'  => 'digital_card' now I want to display the ACF field from the selected post my ACF field name is business_name

```
    $options = array();
    $posts = get_posts( array(
     'post_type'  => 'digital_card'
        ) );

        foreach ( $posts as $key => $post ) {
            $options[$post->ID] = get_the_title($post->ID);
                }

        $this->add_control(
            'card_title',
            [
                'label' => __( 'Select Posts', 'plugin-domain' ),
                'label_block' => ('bool'),
                'type' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::SELECT,
                'multiple' => true,
                'options' => $options,
                
            ]
        );
```

`<h1><?php the_field('business_name', want to pass selected id here ); ?></h1>`

Comment: what is the return type of this field `business_name`

Comment: @Bhautik the return type of the field  `business_name ` is **text**

Comment: What is `business_name` contain?

Comment: business_name have a text input field

Comment: what will you enter on that text input field?

Comment: I have Entered VB Innovatives

Answer (score 0):

you need to create function for example

```
get_selected_post(){
$settings = $this->get_settings_for_display(); 
$selectedOption=$settings('card_title'); 
return $selectedOption
}
```

then call the function in your control

```
'default'=>self::get_selected_post()
```

Comment: Please be more specific, it is not clear what `$this` refers to, as you call the function with `self::`.